# need help with sshfs

Tags: linux, ssh, sshfs

I can't get `sshfs` to work, no matter what I try it won't accept my password.

My hostname is `netnoob44` and my username is `seeder`, and I am trying to use it like this.

```
sudo sshfs -o allow_other,default_permissions $USER@localhost:$HOME  /mnt/sharedfs -p 22222
```

It then asks me for my password:

```
[sudo] password for seeder: 
[sudo] password for seeder:
```

I enter my password, it doesn't work.

This works.

```
sudo ping 1.1.1.1
[sudo] password for seeder: 
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=8.97 ms
```

This works.

```
seeder@netnoob44 ~ $ sudo mkdir test1
[sudo] password for seeder: 
seeder@netnoob44 ~ $
```

What is going on? Why won't this work?

I'm not locked out, I can still sign in and out fine and use `sudo` for anything else.

Comment: are you able to log in with
ssh $USER@localhost:$HOME 
?

Comment: The fact that you're seeing two `sudo` prompts means `sudo` doesn't accept your password.

Comment: Have you searched the `sudo`-related log (depending on your system it may be, for instance, `/var/log/auth.log`, or the systemd journal (see `journalctl`) if you are using `systemd-journald`) for errors?

Answer (score 1):

First I'd check if you are able to ssh into the remote computer using `ssh -p PORT USER@IP:/PATH`.  If this doesn't work then the issue is not with `sshfs` but with plain `ssh`.

If that works create a completely empty new directory using `mkdir /tmp/TEMPORARY_MOUNTPOINT` and afterwards try to mount the remote file system using `sshfs -p PORT USER@IP:/PATH /tmp/TEMPORARY_MOUNTPOINT`.

I'm not sure why you need to use `sudo` for that, on my system I don't need root privileges for `sshfs` (I'm using `Debian Stable`).